# How to Redirect Users to Different Portals As per their Type in Asp.Net Core?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have Two Different Types of User: Admin and Customer Both USer have their own portal.. I have a same login page and i want user to be redirected to their own portals and cant access other portal by any means... Please Do help what can be the solution for this

Comment: You have to use a role-based authentication process as per requirement.

Comment: As a supplement, check this [tutorial](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/10/16/aspnet-core-3-role-based-authorization-tutorial-with-example-api).